# Find Primes in Pi

Tags: code-golf, math, primes, pi

## Primes are everywhere...

they hide inside Pi

3.141592653**58979**3238**462643**3832**795028841**971693993751

Let's get those primes!

## The Challenge

Given as input an integer `n>0`, find out how many primes are hidden inside the first `n` digits of `Pi`

## Examples

For `n=3` we should search for primes in `[3,1,4]`. There are 2 Primes `(3,31)`, so your code should output `2`
For `n=10` , the first 10 digits are `[3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3]` and your code should output `12` because `[2, 3, 5, 31, 41, 53, 59, 653, 4159, 14159, 314159, 1592653]` were hidden (and found!)

## Test Cases

input -> output

```
1->1  
3->2  
13->14  
22->28  
42->60  
50->93

150->197  
250->363  
500->895
```

## Rules

Your code must be able to **find all primes at least for `n=50`**
Yes, you can **hardcode the first 50 digits** of `Pi` if you like
**Entries hardcoding the answers are invalid**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).Shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: _"you can hardcode the first 50 digits of Pi if you like"_. First problem solved! Now for the golfed primality test on up to 50-digit integers... O_o (This is a nice challenge, but solid math built-ins or libraries are probably required.)

Comment: First 50 values (thanks to Mathematica): `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 9, 9, 12, 12, 12, 14, 21, 24, 25, 25, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 32, 33, 33, 39, 39, 42, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 48, 51, 54, 60, 60, 64, 72, 74, 79, 82, 88, 88, 93]`

Comment: For math-illiterate languages: would it be against the spirit of the challenge to encode the results instead?

Comment: @Arnauld the spirit of challenge is... freedom!

Comment: @totallyhuman That sequence not even in OEIS yet! Time for your claim to fame?

Comment: IMO allowing hardcoding of the first 50 values is detrimental to this challenge. This challenge is basically two parts, 1) try to compress the first 50 values, or 2) actually do the challenge.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam That is exactly the reason I picked 50. If someone can't "actually do the challenge" or the language he/she knows can't do it, then there is a second chance which costs +50 bytes. Are you actually going to do the challenge or you are here just to downvote?

Comment: This has nothing to do with languages not being able to do it, Python for example should be able to properly calculate it, but there is no reason to do so, because hardcoding is that much shorter.

Comment: Usually in these kind of challenges, where calculation becomes harder/slower/memory intensive, it is enough for the program to work theoretically, instead of setting an arbitrary cutoff **and** allowing hardcoding.

Comment: Is it me, or are the entries hardcoding the _answers_ against the rules (they only allow "_Yes, you can hardcode the first 50 **digits** of Pi if you like_")?

Comment: @TripeHound You are absolutely right! Entries hardcoding the answers are invalid

Comment: @BillSteihn Updating rules after there are several answers is against the spirit of this website. Have you posted this question in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1)? You would have had feedback really early that hardcoded answers would come in.

Comment: @BillSteihn also, this should say: distinct primes.

Comment: Much of the above discussion could be eliminated and the problem made much more general and useful if instead of "pi", the program must handle an arbitrary string of digits.  "pi" could then simply be a test case (as could "e" and √2).

Answer (score 20):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>10</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

-2 bytes thanks to Adnan (`p` vectorises)

```
<žsþŒÙpO
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5ui@4sP7jk46PLPA//9/Q2MA)** (will work up to n=98413 but will be very slow even for n=50 due to the need to test such large numbers for primality - TIO times out at 60 seconds for n=50.)

#### How?

```
<žsþŒÙpO - implicitly push input, n
<        - decrement = n-1
 žs      - pi to that many decimal places (i.e. to n digits)
   þ     - only the digits (get rid of the decimal point)
    Œ    - all sublists
     Ù   - unique values
      p  - is prime? (vectorises) 1 if so, 0 otherwise
       O - sum
         - implicitly print the top of the stack
```

Comment: `<žsþŒÙpO` should work for 8 bytes

Comment: Ah yeah `p` vectorises thanks!

Comment: Yes! Finally a very short code golf answer that I actually understand! :D

Answer (score 11):

## Mathematica, 76 bytes

```
Tr[1^Union@Select[FromDigits/@Subsequences@#&@@RealDigits[Pi,10,#],PrimeQ]]&
```

Comment: Oh, no fair, I'm not familiar with Mathematica golf. :P (+1)

Comment: @totallyhuman We posted this at the same time. this is so weird!

Comment: I golfed my answer using some of the syntactical tricks but I kept the functions I used before. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: `Tr[1^...]` That is a clever way of finding the length of the list, nice!

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>104</s> <s>97</s> 90 bytes

```
Length@DeleteDuplicates@Select[FromDigits/@Subsequences@First@RealDigits[Pi,10,#],PrimeQ]&
```

Hahahaha, I managed to make this work. I have no idea how to use Mathematica. XD

Input:

```
[50]
```

Comment: you posted some seconds ahead of me. and our answers are very much alike! +1

Comment: Are you sure about the numbers you just posted (double check the rounding of the digits) I see slightly different results [using Python and sympy](https://tio.run/##ZU/NCoMwDD7rU@Rmi04oYxfBp/AoHtxWXcDGLq2CT@9qQTwst3z5/mI3/5npvu8DzwbcZuwGaOzMHtBZRqMLsJgOMwMBEnBPoxaqgIeSVZpYbDwjjbXzLCyWeu2nQVCupGyrm@pK1nbqX1pkZVZkmUyThfC76GZ5uih0UIPTXpxGrfM9@0rTu4MjNK5XMMmIhvOFRUoeKsXY0Cn4eEEFuMUIFfnrwf5LxuH8URyKVYbZ0/0H)

Comment: @JonathanAllan `50 96` The OP says 50 digits contain 93 primes, so Sympy's accuracy might be off..?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Is Sympy using a probabilistic or a deterministic primality test? (Same question for Mathematica's PrimeQ.)

Comment: @Arnauld good point, not sure.

Comment: First deviation is at n=12: sympy's pi yields `3.14159265359` and finds 15 primes (rather than the 12 reported by Mathematica): `[2, 3, 5, 31, 41, 53, 59, 359, 653, 4159, 14159, 314159, 1592653, 4159265359, 314159265359]`

Comment: ^... I see that the `evalf` of sympy means rounding occurs :/

Comment: @JonathanAllan which are the 15 sympy's primes?

Comment: @BillSteihn I listed them above - but I see that pi should be `3.14159265358` not `3.14159265359` (last digit). I thought adding 1 to the digit length and truncating would have avoided that, but I was wrong.

Comment: @Downvoter I'm afraid I must sincerely ask you. Why? ;-;

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>274</s> <s>237</s> <s>207</s> <s>194</s> 189 bytes

*-37 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard! -14 bytes thanks to Mr.Xcoder.*

Hardcodes the first 50 digits of *pi* but manually computes everything else.

```python
x=int(input());l="31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751"[:x]
print(sum(all(i%m for m in range(2,i))for i in{int(i)for w in range(x)for i in[l[j:j-~w]for j in range(x-w)]}-{1}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoMwFET3/YogFBKoYHLzuha/RFy46COiUayiReyvp9VF2@WcOcx0z@HeeghhzpwfqPPdOFDGznUWAZdcodAKlEWDIMBKLbQEsCAMqkRYKzkarhEQwSge5elcHLp@W3qMDS3rmrpjQ65tTxriPOlLf7tQcXKMbcx92LLf7nH6KfO3z@u8Sqv4NRUbqf6UeGLFGi98ZSwEnrwB)

Comment: [You could save a bunch of bytes](https://tio.run/##RY1dC4IwFIbv@xUjiHZSo7PjdAv6JWMXXvQxmVPMkAh/u7kiunxfnoenew63NtA8@5PZNVXHXRjSNWGOUotCklS61CRI5YUociJFotTyIJTKUZdYaNKaSolrsOa4uIvfPQYOYFddH7c/B24cu7Q9c8yFV/y2233dusBj7z70qQOACIwLwPoqXM8c0yh6SBB@qvGmPtbJaONR/9EvmI0LaqfshZO7sMp77jbNJ9v8URFTFmCe8fAG "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: `l=list("31415...)` should save ~40 chars. And that change lets you replace `map(str,i)` with just `i`.

Comment: [You could save another bunch of bytes (200)!](https://tio.run/##RctLCoMwFIXheVcRCoUEFby5eQpdiThwYNtIjGIVKeLarVqow/Pzne4zvNqA6@rvVwQB0nIlURqrLXI0QnElEA1ybWXKjRFgNSiL1qKWcM0zFwbqQjcOlLHi0vX7fo8NLb2n7taQR9uThrhA@jI8K8pjx9je3Nbm43zM6SQQ@ypQzyL4w9zndVZHU7GH@qQ/mEwbLZZkhoWxdYX0Cw)

Comment: [195 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYtLCoMwFAD3PUUQCglUMHn5PaEnERcubBuJUfwgRezV0@pG6HKGmf49vboAMfp7AlxyhUIrUBYNggArtdASwIIwqDJhreRouEZABKN4UuQuTNSFfp4oY@WlH3Ye55ZW3lN3bcmjG0hLXCBDFZ41FTfH2O7cz63HfOByJr4O1J9R4Ysmb9LPUu6m@e/ShZVbuvKNsRh59gU) by removing some strange code.

Comment: [194 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYzRCoIwGEbve4oRBBskuP2b22/4JOKFF1aTOcUUDbFXX@lFdfmdc/i653BvPYTgsiNwyRWKRIEyqBEEGJmIRAIYEBpVLIyRHDVPEBBBK37MU@sHan03DpSx4jJnrvLUsUPXb@IxNrR0jtpTQ65tTxpiPelLf6uoOFvGNmY/bNlf9jn9kvnrc5fXaR29pmIj9V8STaxYo4WvjIXA4zc) by declaring `len(l)`

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>156</s> 123 bytes

```
cat(cumsum(c(1,1,0,1,1,4,1,0,0,3,0,0,2,7,3,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,0,6,0,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,3,6,0,4,8,2,5,3,6,0,5))[scan()])
```

Super interesting solution. Working on a proper one.

Saved 33 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe.

## R (+ numbers and gmp), 198 bytes

```
function(n,x=unique(gmp::as.bigz(unlist(sapply(1:n,function(x)substring(gsub("[.]","",numbers::dropletPi(50)),x,x:n))))))min(length(x),sum(sapply(sapply(x[x>0&!is.na(x)],gmp::factorize),length)==1))
```

Proper solution. Takes `n` as input.

Uses `numbers::dropletPi(50)` to generate the first 50 decimal places of pi. `gsub` removes the decimal point. `substring` takes every possible substring (surprise surprise) of pi up to `n`.

The returned list is flattened and converted to `gmp`'s `bigz` format. This format is required to store integers of length 50. `unique` takes the unique values of that vector. This result gets stored in `x`.

Then we check for primality. This is tricky, because there are a bunch of edge-cases and annoyances:

- For high `n`, there is a `0` in pi. This leads to substrings with a leading zero. `as.bigz` produces `NA`s with that, which have to be removed.
- On a similar note, the substring `"0"` will crash `gmp::factorize`, so has to be removed as well.
- For `n=1`, `x = 3`. Which in itself is ok, but the `bigz` representation of `3` is iterable, so `sapply` will get confused and report 16 primes. To this end we take the minimum of the length of the vector `x`, and the amount of primes in it.
- `gmp::isprime` can't seem to reliably handle the large numbers reliably. So instead we use `gmp::factorize` and check of the length of the output is 1.

So in all, we remove `0` and `NA` from `x`. We factorize all of `x` and check for the length. We count the number of occurrences of `1` and return the `min(occurences, length(x))`.

Comment: there you are! Now let's see if someone out there can outgolf this with a more interesting solution. could be you!

Comment: use `cumsum(c(1,1,0,1,1,4,1,0,0,3,0,0,2,7,3,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,0,6,0,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,3,6,0,4,8,2,5,3,6,0,5))` instead of your vector for 123 bytes :)

Comment: @Giuseppe Nice one. That 'compression' will definitely beat any legit solution.

Comment: I think it's impossible in R without hardcoding or introducing another package since R has only 32-bit ints, which will certainly not represent a 50-digit integer.

Comment: The solution I am currently working on uses both `numbers` and `gmp`. The problem is getting a 50 digit representation of pi, along with primality tests for such values. `numbers::dropletPi` handles the first, but its `isPrime` is unsatisfactory. Same for `gmp::isprime`. So I am currently using `gmp::factorize` and checking for `length()==1`. However, for `n=1` we would get a bigz representation of `3`, which is iterable in itself (because of how bigz works) so it throws off `sapply`.

Comment: Maybe this can be turned into a recursive solution, removing one of the `sapply` calls in the definition of `x`. I seem to be thinking a lot in terms of recursion lately....

Comment: Yeah, I may think about this some more as well. [82 hardcoded bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREOjtCTNIiTfM69EQ0lBUTFGSVldQ0NDW1tb18TcwsIaAuwdHNzcPL0hwD8oNDo6Pj0zr7C8vEZJU9fYUDO6ODkxT0MzVvO/icF/AA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: Entries hardcoding the answers are invalid. You may only hardcode the first 50 digits of Pi. I think you should remove the first answer

Comment: [161 bytes](https://tio.run/##Nco9DsIwDEDhvcfIEluykCq2iHAGdsrQljREal2TnwEQZw9FiOkb3ou1ToXHHFYGxpdYn8oAuut2mrQmLsvgYjLmGleZXT6F7cJG7HalHAN7EGoNU3QCX5399cLhXhzIWY5KXbBRYVLAhz0xpbJA6kXmxx8hv4gxUz/mNYanQ5od@3xDa1vEd60f "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @Giuseppe I can't run this yet, but by the looks of it, would "028" and "28" be counted as duplicates? I don't see anything that accounts for this

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam you're right, it'll crash on that, and for `0` as well...

Comment: [161 bytes, again](https://tio.run/##NYw7DsIwEETvstVaWaFAaWHOQE9ASoJjLCWbjT8FiLsbI8QUM09TvFDKlHlMfmVkEpPZb9mii3lAuLXNu@t2QABUj5iCZ4ecl8GGqPU9rDLbdPbIilrNzZ6CFfyRNbXVN@AnQD4eiKtkwdiLzM//yEVOAFdyi2g99WNag39ZRbNllx7KmOoo5QM "R – Try It Online") (I actually tested this time :P)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>59</s> 32 bytes

*-27 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer.*

```
“!⁶⁷¬,6½ạEC.wʠ€Ẉ!+Ẉfṭ¡’Ṿḣ³ẆVQÆPS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUoAtf9qZWxsef//4oCcIeKBtuKBt8KsLDbCveG6oUVDLnfKoOKCrOG6iCEr4bqIZuG5rcKh4oCZ4bm@4bijwrPhuoZWUcOGUFP///8xMA)

### Explanation

```
“...’Ṿḣ³ẆVQÆPS

“...’           compressed string that evaluates to first 50 digits of pi (314159...)
     Ṿ          uneval; stringify
      ḣ³        first n characters of the string where n is the first command-line argument
        Ẇ       all sublists
         V      convert all elements to integers
          Q     deduplicate
           ÆP   convert all prime elements to 1 and others to 0
             S  sum
```

Comment: Why did you spam this with answers?

Comment: Because nobody else was answering, and I hit rep cap anyways. :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
#ṗumdQ↑İπ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/nhzumluSmBj9omHtlwvuH///@GBgA)

Freezes beyond n=10 on tio. Reverse of the 05AB1E program.